# ArchGIS Javascript Application , the TemplatePicker shows text "No information available" when I zoom in.

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api, arcgis-server

The template picker for editing looks like this when the zoom levels are minimum (expanded or zoomed out)[image: Zoomed out editing mode]

But when i zoom in and start editing, the template picker does not work as expected.[image]

The reason why this may be occurring is because i have defined a feature layer, at the zoom level where the template does not function as expected, as follows,

```
featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(featureLayerUrls[2],
        {
            mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
            infoTemplate: infoTemplate,
            outFields: ["*"]
        });
```

This may be conflicting with the template picker.

Is there a work around for this problem?

### Solutions tried:

1. Disabled the info window at the zoomed in level so that only the template picker info window functions. This did not work. clearly.

### Idea:

I am planning to disable the zoom to this extent if nothing works out. But I cannot find any function for esri.Map that enables me to fix the max zoom level outside the constructor. Let me know if anyone can thing of another way?

The link to the application is: http://carto.gis.gatech.edu/gttree-viewer

### How to reproduce issue:

1. Select "Edit" and click on existing shape on the map. The editing
   template shows up as given in image1.
2. Click stop editing
3. Zoom in to the last level over the shape and select "Edit" and click on
   the shape. The template shows "no information available".

Any feedback is appreciated!!!! :)

Comment: i am not able to find the EDIT option in the application link....